# How can I set up an onclickListner to open a youtube video from an array list

Tags: android, arraylist, youtube

https://github.com/tony10toes/Supporter2

I have an array list of youtube videos.When the user clicks on the video I want it to open in a new window. I am getting an error on the Url in the ArrayList 
[error message][1]

and 
How do I open it in a new window? I have set up an onclick listener but I am confused about how to use the position to show the youtube video selected

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                     // Get the {@link Video} object at the given position the user clicked on
                 Video currentVideo = videos.get(position);

                    currentVideo.equals(currentVideo.getVideoResourceUrl());
                    Intent storiesIntent = new Intent(StoriesActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);

                    startActivity(storiesIntent);
```

From Video Activity

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

            youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
            youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {

              player.cueVideo("Ju67yUUVnts"); // Hard coded because I cant figure out how to get the url string in here
            }
        }
```

From Video Adapter

```
public class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Video>  {

    /** Resource ID for the background color for this list of Videos */
    private int mColorResourceId;
    public VideoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Video> Videos, int colorResourceId) {
        super(context, 0, Videos);
        mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Get the {@link Video} object located at this position in the list
        Video currentVideo = getItem(position);
       // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID default_text_view.
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text_view);
        // Get the default translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
        // the default TextView.
        descriptionTextView.setText(currentVideo.getDescriptionVideoId());

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
        if (currentVideo.hasImage()) {
            // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
            imageView.setImageResource(currentVideo.getImageResourceId());
            // Make sure the view is visible
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Set the theme color for the list item
        View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
        // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
        // Set the background color of the text container View
        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
        // the ListView.
        return listItemView;
    }}
```

Very new to Stack overflow. Thanks In advance

Comment: You didnt post the error you get!

Comment: The error was: Video() in Video cant be applied to: VideoResourseUrl : (expected parameters ) Java lang String (Actual Arguments) R.string.stories1Url (int)